# Parameter in Data Flow SQL Query

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to use Parameter (Date) in SQL Query of a Data Flow in ADF via Pipeline, where the value is coming from a pipeline Variable.

I could pass the parameter but the execution is giving me a following error.

> The store configuration is not defined. This error is potentially
> caused by invalid parameter assignment in the pipeline.

Now there is a solution available for a similar but not exact issue which is to check or uncheck the Expression checkbox of a Data flow parameter, so I did following steps.

1. Did check/uncheck the Expression checkbox for the parameter
   (remember, this is Date datatype parameter, so expression is not
   valid for Date type Parameter). I did it by first passing the string
   parameter (with checked expression checkbox) and than let Dataflow
   convert the string to date and store it inside another Parameter
   which is date).
2. I tried passing directly to Date type parameter to Dataflow
   parameter (here expression checkbox is not applicable for a reason).

None of the above trials worked.

Note, I don't want to use the Dynamic Content in Data Flow query as the Source Query is complicated and Concatenate will be a big mess in that case

Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: what is the store name and what parameter you are giving?

Comment: I have not setup any store. I am trying to pass the date parameter to ADF Data Flow in orer to load the Delta as part of daily load